# What are the recomendation for dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19/18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows, windows-10, bios

What are the best practices to configure BIOS/Firmware settings for dual boot Ubuntu install alongside Windows 10?

I've turned off the "Fast Initialization" option on my computer, just because I've tried two other times a year ago and I failed. In that times, I've followed the tutorial the right way (I think).

When it failed the last time, it was when the GRUB leaded only to Ubuntu, if I selected the Windows option, the GRUB returned again, leading me to an infinite loop between Windows and GRUB.
My files, however, weren't lost.

---

*I'm installing Ubuntu 18.04 because the 19 version gave Kernel Panic at me.

Here is the picture of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TyhI.jpg *<-- 19 Ubuntu ISO*

The error when the 18.04 version is booted is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpADj.jpg

---

P.S.: Detailing my BIOS and Board *(informations from CPU-Z)*:

**UEFI:** Yes

**vendor:** ASRock

**model:** H61M-HVS

***Complete System details: https://pastebin.com/izzX7Gv4***~

---

**EDIT2:** In conversation by chat, I've put the 18 iso and the problem is the same. When I put the ISO and change the boot order by ASRock BIOS GUI, booting by **USB** Flash Drive (not UEFI, there is an option for this too), it loads the screen with an icon of accessibility and another one for a keyboard, then there is a black screen putting an error (the image above)

I've tried to put the same USB Flash Drive in another computer, but another error is gave to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pacss.jpg *<-- Tested with 18.04 Ubuntu ISO*

---

**EDIT3:** I'm now closing this question only related to dual-boot tips. In relation to the problem in BIOS, I'll create another post.

Comment: Secure Boot can also, sometimes, be problematic, if not disabled for the installation of the new OS. Once installed and both Windows and Ubuntu reboot OK, you can turn it back on.

Comment: Are you doing fresh install for both, or do you have windows 10 already installed?

Comment: You show BIOS from 2012, is that BIOS only or UEFI. It was in 2012 and release of Windows 8 that Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning.  If UEFI/BIOS is that old there should be an update available from vendor also. You need to update it. What brand/mode system. UEFI/BIOS settings vary by vendor a lot.

Comment: @oldfred Hmm... Will that harm my 18's installation too?

Comment: @BernardWei Windows 10 is already installed

Comment: @K7AAY What is secure boot?

Comment: @oldfred My board is ASRock H61M-HVS

Comment: @oldfred My bios is American Megatrends P2.50 09/18/2012

Comment: I did the same. I have windows 10 pre-install on my laptop before I install ubuntu 18.04. I'll post the steps I took, hope that may help.

Comment: @BernardWei I'm not on a laptop. This PC was first installed with W7. But story goes and I've installed W10 myself.

Comment: So do you have a second drive for Ubuntu or you need to install it on the same drive. I have done it on separate drive on my desktop too.

Comment: @BernardWei Same drive. (C:)

Comment: A few more questions. are you using UEFI bios and install windows with EFI booting? If so the steps are a lot cleaner as both Windows and Ubuntu will install the EFI boot on the EFI partition, and switch around both boot setup is much simpler. I.e., windows boot manager can see Ubuntu, and Ubuntu boot manager can see Windows, and can boot each other without issues. For MBR Windows installation, it's the old way and will need to chain boot from Grub, not very nice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96404/discussion-between-dyefferson-azevedo-and-bernard-wei).

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO and run a media check ion the USB?  Looks like there was an error unpacking the initramdisk on your image link.

Comment: @ubfan1 This question was split. Look at this topic to see the info you need: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159707/i-cant-boot-to-flash-drive-containing-ubuntu

*Answering you: yes

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to check:

1. install Ubuntu the same way windows is installed: legacy or EFI. Otherwise you can only boot one and need to pick the other way by entering BIOS and selecting it.
2. disable fast boot in BIOS if available.
3. disable [secure boot](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006942/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html) in BIOS if available.
4. if you use an SSD set it to AHCI.

If the installer is created with EFI enabled you can rename (or remove) `/sys/firmware/efi/` on the pendrive (by mounting it as writeable) and it will install the system in legacy.

Command line to check if the live session was started with UEFI or legacy BIOS:

```
$ [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
UEFI
```

It is easiest to create unallocated space on the partitions you want to use for Ubuntu. Makes it easier to recognize. Try to put base Ubuntu (/) on an SSD if available. Quicker boot and quicker loading of configuration. In theory you can use D: to store your personal files, though I would advice to create a partition to store these.

Comment: How to check if Windows is legacy BIOS or UEFI? Your command line instructions were for linux terminal, wasn't it?

Comment: we only support Ubuntu on here so yes. I do not know how to check on windows (XP was my last one ;)) But you should be able to see it in BIOS at the "boot options". a bootable partition will state it is EFI