# I can't boot to Flash Drive containing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb, 19.04, bios

## What is happening?

I've used Rufus to create a bootable pen-drive with Ubuntu 19's ISO. Then going into BIOS and selecting USB to boot first (Not UEFI option of the same), then I received this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TyhI.jpg

I contacted a Discord server for help. Its administrator said me to try 18.04 version instead. I did the same process with Rufus, now following this tutorial: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0.

Then booting by the same way I received this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpADj.jpg

After this I've tried to put this same USB with Ubuntu 18.04 in another computer, which I don't have the specs to show, only saying that the specs are lower than my actual computer. In that another computer, the error was this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pacss.jpg.

I've hashchecked the ISO in the two cases, all hashs was the same as official provided by Ubuntu's website.

---

## My Motherboard and BIOS specs

**UEFI:** Yes

**vendor:** ASRock

**model:** H61M-HVS

***Complete System details: https://pastebin.com/izzX7Gv4***

*I'm on a Windows 10 computer, all instructions below need to be run in CMD or Powershell.*

---

## Edits and Progress

- I've tried Fedora on the same flash drive and there was an error too. (I'll not post it here because it's not the target of the forum)
- I think there could be happening something with the flash drive.

Comment: Very first line of the first and third tries: "LZMA data is corrupt." Re-download the .iso images and re-make the USB.

Comment: @user535733 I don't know if I am downloadind the isos from the right places though.

Comment: The correct place is https://ubuntu.com/download

Comment: @user535733 It's not the ISO, as the system Fedora isn't working as well

Comment: Well, it's either the hardware or the software. If you are saying that it's not the Ubuntu software on the LiveUSB....

Comment: @user535733 Is there a chance of the problem being the pen-drive?

Comment: There's not one chance, there's two chances. Chance number 1 is the pen-drive and chance number 2 is the computer that you're booting it on. The Ubuntu Minimal CD/USB is designed to boot under the worst conditions. It's a special easy to boot Ubuntu ISO from Canonical.

Comment: @karel So you are asking me to boot into Ubuntu Minimal? Where do I download it?

Comment: [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/)

Comment: @karel I am planning to do a dual boot. Is there a tutorial of dual booting and installing in this system?

Comment: [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/)